# SKSpriteNode not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im using a protocol for all my game sprite which looks like the following:

```
import SpriteKit

protocol GameSprite{

    var imageSprite : SKSpriteNode {get set}

    func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size:CGSize)

    func onTap()

}
```

im then creating a crow sprite with the following:

```
    import SpriteKit

class Crow: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite{

    var imageSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "crow.png")
    var flyAnimation = SKAction()

    func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) {

        parentNode.addChild(self)
        //createAnimations()
        self.position = position
        self.size = size
        //self.runAction(flyAnimation)
    }

    func onTap() {

    }
}
```

and finally im calling the sprite to the game scene:

```
let crow2 = Crow()
        crow2.spawn(world, position: CGPoint(x: 220, y: 210))
```

im getting no errors, but for some reason the sprite doesnt show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say either:

```
func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) {

        parentNode.addChild(self.imageSprite)
        //createAnimations()
        self.imageSprite.position = position
        self.imageSprite.size = size
        //self.runAction(flyAnimation)
    }
```

Or this

```
func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)) {
        self.texture = SKTexture(image: image)
        parentNode.addChild(self)
        //createAnimations()
        self.position = position
        self.size = size
        //self.runAction(flyAnimation)
    }
```

Which is probably closer to your original intent. The Crow class is a subclass of SKSpritNode, it doesn't really need a sprite node property, because it is itself a sprite node. If you want it to be an "image node," you just need to texture it with an image. So pass in an image and set it's texture property.

Comment: Thank you, this worked brilliantly.  if you dont mind explaining why was this happening?, i thought self would have automatically have applied to the image sprite?